# Python is_file not working on a mounted raw image

Tags: python

Pathlib's is_file doesn't seem to work when running on a loop-backed mounted device

I have a text file with file paths in it. The files correspond to a loop-back mounted .raw image.

```
cat diff.txt | grep kvm-recheck-rcu.sh
usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-17/tools/testing/selftests/rcutorture/bin/kvm-recheck-rcu.sh
```

These are mounted underneath a mount point

```
ls /mnt/new/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-17/tools/testing/selftests/rcutorture/bin/kvm-recheck-rcu.sh
/mnt/new/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-17/tools/testing/selftests/rcutorture/bin/kvm-recheck-rcu.sh
```

In the example below `is_file` will always return False.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib
import os


size = 0
mount_point = pathlib.Path("/mnt/new")
with open("/tmp/diff.txt", mode="r") as f:
    while True:
        line = f.readline()

        p = pathlib.Path(line)

        mounted_file = mount_point / p

        if "kvm-recheck-rcu.sh" in mounted_file.name:
            print(f"debug: {mounted_file}:{mounted_file.is_file()}")

        if mounted_file.is_file():
            print(mounted_file)
            size = size + os.stat(str(mounted_file))

        if not line:
            break

print(size)
```

The debug statement will print

```
debug: /mnt/new/usr/src/linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-17/tools/testing/selftests/rcutorture/bin/kvm-recheck-rcu.sh
:False
```

Comment: Notice how there's a line break in your debug output, when there isn't one in the actual string being printed?  `.readline()` leaves the newline character in the string that is read, so you're trying to use a pathname that ends with a newline - which is rather unlikely to match any actual file on the disk.

Comment: Right.  `s.strip()` is your friend here.

Comment: Yep, that was it. I should have sanitized the input.
@jasonharper you commented first, do you want to answer the question.